# Can't we just mutate state ..? What is the side-effect..?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

As suggested at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates , we are suggested to make functional update via below method:

```js
function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

thats a pretty low level example, so mostly we are faced by situation we are supposed to pass complex state to the component and in such cases below method works really well :

```js
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ number: 10 });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setState((state) => {
            state.number++; //+ I am concerned about this mutation though.
            return { ...state };
          });
        }}
      >
        {state.number}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

PROOF OF WOKABILITY: Codesanbdox link for my code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutate-j8mtn).

but this is not generally seen by people to update state in their OSS with react, why is it so..?

Can anybody help me if using this form of update causes any undesirable sideeffects, if so can please provide such a codesandbox instance to replicate that behaviour..?

Thanks.

Comment: In your example, you are not breaking any rule-of-thumb. You change the previous state and set a copy of the changed state. That is okay to do. In your onClick, if you did `state.number++` without setState, then your component wouldn't update

Comment: Thanks for responding..! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your example works it is not the perfect and the most bug free way of writing things.

The reason your code works is because you are shallow cloning the state and returning it causing the `Object.is` check in react to fail and re-render the component. **Also note that spread syntax does a one level cloning of the object only**.

The problem arises when you update nested variables like abovee and then pass on to some other component as props which then extend PureComponent or use `React.meemo` to optimize on re-renders

Eg:

```
const SomeComp = memo((props) => {
  return <span>{props.nestedKey.id}</span>;
});
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ number: 10, nested: { id: 1 } });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setState((state) => {
            state.number++;
            state.nested.id++;
            return { ...state };
          });
        }}
      >
        {state.number}
        <SomeComp nestedKey={state.nested} />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you look at the above code, even though id value is updates, SomeComp doesn't re-render to update its value

[DEMO sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutate-forked-lpdyc)

The right way to update your state is like

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ number: 10 });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setState((state) => {
            return { ...state, number: state.number + 1 };
          });
        }}
      >
        {state.number}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks to mak my case fail, I appreciate your help and time spend to help me. Thanks a lot!! <3

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example that your code did not work, result in unexpected outcome. With complicated state, make sure to deep clone it.
Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-cloud-g0ec2?file=/src/App.js:0-716) link

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ number: 10, arr: [] });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setState((state) => {
            state.number++;
            state.arr.push(1);
            return { ...state };

            /* 
            My Solution : Deep clone state
            const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
            clone.number++;
            clone.arr.push(1);
            console.log(clone);
            return { ...clone }; 
            */
          });
        }}
      >
        {state.number}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you disable StrictMode it works well though, check it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-babbage-7cypb?file=/src/index.js
What do say..?

Comment: Thanks for responding..!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function App({initialCount}) {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(initialCount);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => ({ prevCount: prevCount - 1}))}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => ({ prevCount: prevCount + 1}))}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App initialCount={{ number: 10 }}/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Don't mutate your state directly

Comment: Thanks for responding..!